# How to execute a php file from nant script?

Tags: php, xml, nant

I want to execute one php file from my nant script. How can I do that.

Any body can help me with a sample code?

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? If you run into any specific problems we can help.

Comment: I tried using this
<exec program="php.exe" basedir="${phpdir}" commandline="php myfile.php"/>. Here I again give the php in command line so it is not working. Thanks for your advise ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [<exec> task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html). You would use the same paramaters as if you were calling the PHP script from the command line.